# base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) is always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I referred to hundreds of posts and no luck yet. The       base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) returns false always.

I am running the MVC application from VS2012 using IIS express. Many people were able to solve this issue with forms based authentication. But i tried that too. 
Please help..

Below is the AuthorizeADAttribute is am using.

```
public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Groups { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
      {

        // var authorized = (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);


            /* Return true immediately if the authorization is not 
            locked down to any particular AD group */
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Groups))
                return true;

            // Get the AD groups
            var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList<string>();

            // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN");
            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,
                                                 IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                 httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
                        return true;
                }
                catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException exc)
                {
                    var msg = String.Format("While authenticating a user, the operation failed due to the group {0} could not be found in Active Directory.", group);
                    System.ApplicationException e = new System.ApplicationException(msg, exc);
                   // ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    var msg = "While authenticating a user, the operation failed.";
                    System.ApplicationException e = new System.ApplicationException(msg, exc);
                    //ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
                    return false;
                }
            }
       }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am passing the group name like this. This works perfect when i run the application from VS2012 using IIS Express. The web.config file is set to
In the IIS settings Forms Based Authentication isenabled. But the URL redirection goes to login.aspx. I dont have any login page in my application

But when I publish the website to IIS. Error page shows up.

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "DevUsers")]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View();
}
```

Comment: We need some context to be able to help you. Please read this sscce.org

Comment: What error page?  What's the error?

Comment: Your question is really confusing and doesn't make a lot of sense.  How can you be using Forms Authentication, but have no login page?  How do you expect your user to login?  You appear to be using Active Directory code in your Authorize attribute, which makes little sense if you're using Forms authentication.

Comment: Ok.. I am completely new to this.. . I just want to restrict the view page display based on AD group. My application doesnt have any login page at all. What should It do..?

Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) works base on roles and group. you may not have the group of 'DevUsers'.
add public string CustomGroups { get; set; } to class and call it like this:

```
[AuthorizeAD(CustomGroups = "DevUsers")]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View();
}
```

in this way which you send the group null then base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) just does the authenticate part and you do the groups and role in your custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply forget about httpcontext getting receive in the method... Stuff can interfere with things...

like this:

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
            {

```
            string Domain = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
            string AdGroups = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdGroups"];


            /* Return true immediately if the authorization is not 
            locked down to any particular AD group */
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AdGroups))
                return true;

            // Get the AD groups
            //var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList();

            WindowsIdentity CurrentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;

            var groups = AdGroups.Split(',').ToList();

            List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups2 = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            // iterate over all groups
            foreach (Principal p in groups2)
            {
                // make sure to add only group principals
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {

                    foreach (var group in groups)
                        try
                        {

                            if (p.ToString().Equals(group.ToString()))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException ex)
                        {
                        }

                    //result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```